# Creating a Stored Procedure in MySQL with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a new stored procedure programatically using the following code:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (MySqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    using (MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = query;

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    trans.Commit();
                }
            }
```

And the following text as the create statement copied from Mysql workbench:

```
static string query = @"
delimiter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `GetParentIds`(IN `tempTableName` VARCHAR(255), IN `id` int)
BEGIN
DECLARE parId INT;
DECLARE curId INT;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempTableName;

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTableName (
node_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   );

 set curId := id;
 get_parents_loop: LOOP
     set parId := null;

     set parId = (select ParentID from {TableName} where ID = curId);

    IF parId is NULL THEN
       LEAVE get_parents_loop;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO tempTableName(node_id) Values (parId);
    set curId := parId;

END LOOP get_parents_loop;
  SELECT *
     FROM tempTableName;
END$$";
```

This procedure is passed an ID of an object which has a parentID and it gets all of the parentIDs of all the parents of the given object and returns them.  The problem comes when I try to run it and I get the following message:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `GetParentIds`(IN `tempTableName` VARCHAR(255),' at line 1"

Any and all Ideas are welcome!

*** EDIT ****
Thanks to all the answers below, this is what finally worked:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetParentIds(IN tempTableName VARCHAR(255), IN id int)
BEGIN
DECLARE parId INT;
DECLARE curId INT;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempTableName;

 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTableName (node_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  );

set curId := id;
get_parents_loop: LOOP
    set parId := null;

    set parId = (select ParentID from TDOs where TDOID = curId);

    IF parId is NULL THEN
       LEAVE get_parents_loop;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO tempTableName(node_id) Values (parId);
    set curId := parId;

END LOOP get_parents_loop;
  SELECT *
    FROM tempTableName;
END;
```

Comment: Try to remove back quotes (back ticks) around procedure and parameter names. They are not needed in your context and my misbehave within the string an may be misinterpreted by the driver

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove `DELIMITER $$` at the beginning and `$$` after last `END`

`DELIMITER` is a **mysql client command** that enables you to change its statement terminator temporarily while you define a stored routine.

If you are defining a stored routine from within a programming interface that does not use the semicolon as a statement terminator, semicolons within stored routine definitions do not present any special issues.

Comment: Excellent Info, I didn't realize it wasn't necessary!

Comment: Thank so much @peterm